# How can I bulk load data into mysql with python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

With psycope, I have copy_from to call postgresql's bulk load command "COPY" to do bulk load, and I can actually reference to stdin and do not need to save files.

However, I cannot find the similar function with pymysql.

So would there be a way that I can bulk load data into mysql by python?

Probably using 'LOAD' command from STDIN and try to write STDIN??

Comment: you can use `to_sql` from pandas

Comment: @Snow That basically transfer data into insert instruction and execute it......

Comment: There's method `multi` to pass multiple values in insert